# Inverse of sum of consecutive numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have an array of integers, and for any given index, I would like to know the value of the array.
However, I do not want to use a for loop to compute the value. Clearly a for loop can be used to determine the value of the array, but that has significant performance limitations in my case.

The first $n$ numbers are 0, the next $n-1$ numbers are 1, the next $n-2$ numbers are 2, and so on, until the last value of the array is just $n$. My question is: is there a closed form for finding the value of the array at any given index, given $n$?

[Plot of array indices vs array values for n = 63](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUujF.png)

Essentially I'm trying to recover a stepwise function that is the sum of consecutive numbers (see plot above).

$\sum_{i=0}^j n-j = idx$ or more precisely, since $idx$ most of the time is not an exact value of this sum

$\sum_{i=0}^j n-j \le idx < \sum_{i=0}^{j+1} n-j$

Is there a way to find $j$ without just looping through values? Or is there a way to guess a close interval of $j$ so that only a few values need to be checked?

I've tried using the formula for the sum of $n$ consecutive numbers, but that hasn't gotten me far. I'd appreciate any ideas for further work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula maybe off a little (for example being off by one index) but I think it's close enough that you can sort out the discrepancies.

Let $k$ be the index in question then the value should be well approximated by:

$$\displaystyle{\Bigg\lfloor n-\frac{\sqrt{8\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}-k\right)+1}-1}{2}\Bigg\rfloor}$$

Comment: Thanks! I checked for values of $n$ up to ~120 and couldn't find a situation where it is off

Comment: @Doubledor then maybe I am second guessing myself too much, it is probably the correct formula. I'm glad that a found a solution to your problem